# Android. Swipe to next tab only if 'if statement' is passed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

In my android app I have an activity with a tablayout and 4 fragment page that I am able to swipe between all of them. But I wanna have a if statement when I am trying to swipe. And swipe only if statement pass.  For example in the first fragment page I have an edit text and wanna be able to swipe to next fragment page only if the editText is not empty. Is this possible? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Will the user type in EditText, or your are setting the data from some where else

Comment: The user will type to the editText